# Go func (*DB) Query return when such a row does not exist

Tags: go

Signature is `func (db *DB) Query(query string, args ...interface{}) (*Rows, error)`.

What does Go `func (*DB) Query` return if the query and call is:

```
rows, err := db.Query("SELECT username FROM userstable WHERE username=$1", registerInstance.Username)
```

when there is no such row in the table `userstable`.

Does it return a non-nil `error` or return empty string value as `Result` and non-nil `error` is returned only when an error occurs?

Comment: This could easily be resolved by trying out the query while debugging. It should return a set of rows, being empty.

Comment: But this is a valid question. It points the difference of the error returns and the empty row cases. Actually this has been revealed by the answer of the @dave. Answer having clues in the documentations does not invalidate a question, yet the answer of the answerer is not included in the documentation link he has provided.

Comment: Nor the problem in hand can be examined in debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you'll definitely want to use `QueryRow` instead of `Query` (assuming you'd only ever get one user with the same username).

From http://go-database-sql.org/retrieving.html

> Go defines a special error constant, called sql.ErrNoRows, which is returned from QueryRow() when the result is empty. This needs to be handled as a special case in most circumstances. An empty result is often not considered an error by application code, and if you don’t check whether an error is this special constant, you’ll cause application-code errors you didn’t expect.

When using `Query`, you'll be looping over the results with something like:

```
rows, err := db.Query("SELECT username FROM userstable WHERE username=$1", registerInstance.Username)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
defer rows.Close()
var users []User
for rows.Next() {
    user = User{}
    err := rows.Scan(&user.Username)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    users = append(users, user)
}
rows.Close()
if (len(users) == 0) {
    //handle this case
}
```

Comment: I have tried to edit the line `users := append(users, user)` to `users = append(users, user)`. But the change must have min 6 chars. So I have deleted the line saved and re edited but this last time it could not save the changes. Noe it seems ok. Change has taken effect.